# Extract email:pass from string

Tags: php

I have text like in the example below

```
$text = "rami@gmail.com:Password
This email is from Gmail
email subscription is valid 

omar@yahoo.com:password 
this email is from yahoo 
email subscription is valid ";
```

I want to be able to retrieve all email:password occurrence in the text without the rest of the description. 
I tried preg_match but it returned 0 results and explode returns all text with the description.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Explode
Str_Pos
Preg_match

```
$text = "rami@gmail.com:Password
This email is from Gmail
email subscription is valid 

omar@yahoo.com:password 
this email is from yahoo 
email subscription is valid ";
```

Comment: Show your attempted `preg_match`.

Comment: user have you seen the request above to post the code you tried?

Comment: user if you just show your attempts then I can post an answer for you that is not static.

Comment: Your question missing vital ingredients like EXACT desired result and your best coding attempt.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to be confident/precise when dealing with unrealistic input strings, but this pattern extracts (does not validate) the `email:password` lines for you.

Match from the start of the line, match the known characters and in the negated character classes include whitespace characters to prevent matching the next line.  You could use `\n` instead of `\s` if you like.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/RpafD))

```
$text = "rami@gmail.com:Password
This email is from Gmail
email subscription is valid 

omar@yahoo.com:password 
this email is from yahoo 
email subscription is valid ";

var_export(preg_match_all('~^[^@\s]+@[^:\s]+:\S+~m', $text, $matches) ? $matches[0]: "none");
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'rami@gmail.com:Password',
  1 => 'omar@yahoo.com:password',
)
```

...hmm, I guess it is okay to allow spaces in a password, but if so, then you cannot logically trim any spaces from the right side of the password.  An alternative pattern to allow spaces which also provides separated capture groups could look like this: (**See [Demo](https://3v4l.org/dd44a) with fringe case where password characters require specific pattern logic to prevent greedy matching in the first capture group.**)

```
var_export(preg_match_all('~([^@\s]+@[^:\s]+):(.*)~', $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER) ? $matches: "none");
```

I am favoring negated character classes `[^...]` over `.` (any character dot) because it allows the use of greedy quantifiers -- this affords the pattern greater efficiency (in terms of step count, anyhow).

Comment: I was going to withhold yhis answer until the question was improved, but Abdur forced my hand.

Comment: I was also waiting for an attempt. Or at least a comment from OP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to capture the email and passwords separately.
I capture anything of any length to a colon then anything again until new line with an optional space.

```
preg_match_all("/(.*@.*):(.*?)\s*\n/", $text, $matches);
$matches = array_combine(["match", "email", "password"], $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["match"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(24) "rami@gmail.com:Password
"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "omar@yahoo.com:password 
"
  }
  ["email"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "rami@gmail.com"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "omar@yahoo.com"
  }
  ["password"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "Password"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "password"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/baeQ0